# Unity/C# Stopwatch If Time Has Elapsed statement (timer > 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Searched the interwebs for a while and got something that pointed me in the right direction so I could get the answer. Thought I'd share it for somebody in the future:

**How to write an if statement in C# for a Stopwatch to check if time as elapsed**

Comment: Your question is essentially _"How to write an if statement in C# for a Stopwatch to check if time as elapsed"_.  [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
public Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

if(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds == 0) {
    // if timer hasn't started
}
```

or

```
if(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 0) {
    // if timer has started
}
```